# Create nested data.tables by collapsing rows into new data.tables

Tags: r, nested, data.table

How can you create a data.table that contains nested data.tables?

#### Example

```
set.seed(7908)
dt <- data.table(x=1:5)[,list(y=letters[1:x],z=sample(1:100,x)),by=x]

dt
##     x y  z
##  1: 1 a 13
##  2: 2 a 27
##  3: 2 b 87
##  4: 3 a 85
##  5: 3 b 98
##  6: 3 c  1
##  7: 4 a 53
##  8: 4 b 81
##  9: 4 c 64
## 10: 4 d 45
## 11: 5 a 28
## 12: 5 b 26
## 13: 5 c 52
## 14: 5 d 55
## 15: 5 e 12
```

#### Desired output

For each unique value of x in dt, collapse the rows and create a data.table with columns y and z that is contained in a single column of dt.  The result should look like this:

```
##    x        dt.yz
## 1: 1 <data.table>
## 2: 2 <data.table>
## 3: 3 <data.table>
## 4: 4 <data.table>
## 5: 5 <data.table>
```

In my actual example I've got several data tables with differing columns that I want to store in a single meta data table.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create the data.table using y and z as the columns, and then wrap that in a list so it can be "stuffed" in a single row.  Wrap that in yet another list, where you assign the resulting column name.  Use `by=x` to do this for each unique value of x.

```
dt2 <- dt[, list(dt.yz=list(data.table(y, z))), by=x]
dt2
##    x        dt.yz
## 1: 1 <data.table>
## 2: 2 <data.table>
## 3: 3 <data.table>
## 4: 4 <data.table>
## 5: 5 <data.table>
```

As Arun points out, using `.SD` is shorter and faster, and may be more convenient:

```
dt2 <- dt[, list(dt.yz=list(.SD)), by=x]
## dt.yz will include all columns not in the `by=`;
## Use `.SDcols=` to select specific columns
```

To get the value of a data.table later, subset the meta data.table (dt2) based on the desired value of x, and then get the first element in the list (which is the nested data.table) of the dt.yz column.

```
dt2[x==5,dt.yz[[1]]]
##    y  z
## 1: a 28
## 2: b 26
## 3: c 52
## 4: d 55
## 5: e 12
```

Comment: You can use `.SD` instead. `dt[, list(dt.yz=list(.SD)), by=x]`

Comment: Hi @Arun.  Yes, that could be more convenient, especially if you have many columns.  It might be slightly faster too, right?

Comment: Right, it'll be faster (and is shorter). `data.table(.)` is slower and `as.data.table(.)` is slightly faster, but makes a copy first. `.SD` on the other hand is available ready.

Comment: Any chance for the reverse process?

Comment: @Arun this is great! This pattern is the `data.table` version of **nest** and **unnest** in the  `tidyverse` (should be promoted more; had been looking for a long time)... @jangorecki the reverse op is: `dt[ , dt.yz[[1]], by = x]`